# Gradle resolution strategy cacheDynamicVersionsFor isn't working

Tags: java, gradle, cache-dependency, dependency-resolution, resolutionstrategy

I want to push Gradle to redownload my SNAPSHOT dependencies every time.
It's possible to do it via `--refresh-dependencies`.
But I want to do it programmatically in a next way:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.cacheDynamicVersionsFor 0, 'seconds'
    resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'
}

dependencies {
    compile(Libraries.staffdetails_biz) { changing = true }
}
```

(I know that if version is SNAPSHOT, no need to add `changing = true`, but added it just in case)

So after that, when I'm running my application `./gradlew clean bootRun --info` 
I see the next log:

```
Downloading https://artifactory.intra.max-it.com/beauty-mvn/jp/co/max/beauty/staffdetails-biz/1.2.0.0-test-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml to /private/var/folders/1t/yrqc_w552kl_8d5bknxkmfd07bv2xj/T/gradle_download937200563233010269bin
Downloading https://artifactory.intra.max-it.com/beauty-mvn/jp/co/max/beauty/staffdetails-biz/1.2.0.0-test-SNAPSHOT/staffdetails-biz-1.2.0.0-test-SNAPSHOT.pom to /private/var/folders/1t/yrqc_w552kl_8d5bknxkmfd07bv2xj/T/gradle_download778741251330227118bin
```

And the issue, that it download the pom file, but doesn't download the jar. What should I change in my buildscript to push it to work as expected?

---

And only If I specify `--refresh-dependencies` it'll download the jar:

```
Downloading https://artifactory.intra.max-it.com/beauty-mvn/jp/co/max/beauty/staffdetails-biz/1.2.0.0-test-SNAPSHOT/staffdetails-biz-1.2.0.0-test-SNAPSHOT.jar to /private/var/folders/1t/yrqc_w552kl_8d5bknxkmfd07bv2xj/T/gradle_download1419898241363246448bin
```