# Having trouble with Gradle dependencies not updating

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a project with 3 common jars shared across multiple repositories. I'm using Intellij 2019.4. In my gradle build, I included the following method:

```
dependencyManagement {
    resolutionStrategy {
        // don't cache SNAPSHOT modules; always retrieve them from the maven cache
        cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'
    }
}
```

That's supposed to tell Gradle not to cache snapshots, but mine are still being cached. I build and install one of the common jars, and the maven repo has it, but the Gradle cache still has a jar from over 24 hours ago. Is there a different method I should be using? I want Gradle to ALWAYS use what's in the .m2 repo.

Comment: Are you sure the outdated jars are actually being used in the build? I don't think Gradle uses the build cache when sourcing artifacts from local repositories. See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sec:case-for-maven-local

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. The changes I make to updated jars aren't being reflected. When I navigate to the source code, it takes me to the jar in the Gradle cache.

Comment: I had the [same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57900891/gradle-resolution-strategy-cachedynamicversionsfor-isnt-working)
And after I've discovered, it looks like gradle has some kind of delay ~1-5min, even though you set up resolutionStrategy 0 seconds

Answer (score 2):

Gradle will only search for modules in the *declared* repositories.

This means that if you need a library, `SNAPSHOT` or not, from you local Maven repository, you need to declare it as a repository in Gradle.

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal() {
        content {
            includeModule("my.org", "someLib")
        }
    }
    // other repositories
}
```

However, there are [caveats](https://docs.gradle.org/6.0.1/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sec:case-for-maven-local) in adding `mavenLocal()` to your repositories, so make sure to use [repository content filtering](https://docs.gradle.org/6.0.1/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sec:repository-content-filtering) to only search your local Maven repo for those `SNAPSHOT` dependencies, as shown above.

Comment: Perhaps I should have posted my whole build file. I already have `mavenLocal()` declared. Is there anything else I should look for?

Comment: Please do add your repository declaration to your question then, and maybe clarify the version of the library you are trying to get. The most likely explanation is ordering as I showed, but there could be something else.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `changing = true` into individual `SNAPSHOT` dependencies' `configClosure`.

```
implementation("group:module:1.0-SNAPSHOT") {changing = true}
```

Then [`cacheChangingModulesFor`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/ResolutionStrategy.html#cacheChangingModulesFor-int-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) should apply to them:

```
configurations.all() {
    resolutionStrategy {
        cacheChangingModulesFor 0, "seconds"
    }
}
```

---

With version `latest.integration`, this would require the build-number added into the version - but, this would keep the build reproducible, since one can switch back to the previous build of the library.

There also is a CLI option `--refresh-dependencies`, which refreshes them all.

The Gradle manual explains it, too: [Declaring a changing version](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:declaring_dependency_with_changing_version).

Forcibly deleting them before build would be another option.